# Excel - Making a sublist based on a text filter

Tags: excel, search, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to implement something similar to what is explained in this article:

http://exceltactics.com/make-filtered-list-sub-arrays-excel-using-small/

For this example, column B has Text, column c has integer values, and column d has text

The formula below works for filtering on values that are >= 1 in column C of my data:

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        B$2:B$11,
        SMALL(
            IF(
                $C$2:$C$11>=1,
                ROW(B$2:B$11)-ROW(B$2)+1
            ),
            ROWS(B$2:B2)
        )
    ),
    ""
)
```

I would like to replace that line with a search function that filters based the text content of a cell (from column D). The following works on a single line (returns 0 if "a" is not contained in the cell, otherwise a value greater than 0).

```
=IFERROR(SEARCH("a",$D2),0)
```

However, combining it with the first function doesn't work:

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        B$2:B$11,
        SMALL(
            IF(
                IFERROR(SEARCH("a",$D$2:$D$11),0)>=1,
                ROW(B$2:B$11)-ROW(B$2)+1
            ),
            ROWS(B$2:B2)
        )
    ),
    ""
)
```

What am I missing from this formula?

Comment: what do you have in your column B, numeric values or text string? and in column C? plz

Comment: @AHC Updated question to include column data types.

Comment: why did you change your search parameter to $D2? can you give a screenshot of your data?

Comment: In my initial question, I made a mistake when I was pasting the code.

Comment: it is very unclear, in your first formula you are filtering based on column C and in the second one based on column D, what is the logic???

Comment: @AHC The first formula uses almost the same formula as the article mentioned, and it was just a test to see if the formula works. But I wanted to filter column D, which is a text column, not the integer column.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the formula IMHO. It worked for me, but I did have problems when I tried to change the original formula in-place with the range selected. If you start off in a new area in the worksheet or just select the top cell in the original range and then pull it down once you've changed it, it's fine. With the range selected, it didn't change the final B2 to B3 etc. as I pulled it down, so just kept getting the first row number repeated.

BTW don't need the ">=1" in the modified part of the formula because any match will give a result >0 which is equivalent to "true"

```
IFERROR(SEARCH("a",$D$2:$D$11),0)
```

See also suggestion for changing the array formulae to ordinary ones before changing them

[Changing array formulae](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/300372-cannot-change-part-array.html)